# How to access a static injected dependency on Play2 application exit

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, guice

I have a Play 2 application which is using Guice to inject a static object (a realtime sensor monitoring object) into Application.java:

*controllers.Application:*

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    @Inject static MonitorService monitorService;
    ...
}
```

*module.Dependencies:*

```
public class Dependencies {
   ....
   @Provides
   @Singleton
   public MonitorService getMonitorService(final MonitorFactory factory) {
       return new MonitorService(factory){
              @Override 
              public MonitorService(Factory factory){
                 return factory.getMonitor();
              }
          }
   }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to access the *factory* or *monitor* object when the play application is exiting in order to shut it down gracefully.  I have looked at hooking into the *GlobalSettings.onStop* but cannot see a way to extract a reference from the *Play.Application* object.  I have tried injecting *MonitorService* into the Global class but it returns a null object so I am assuming the *Dependencies* object has been destroyed by this stage.

I am also aware this approach may be totally wrong ;)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using the [Typesafe plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/).

AFAIK, unfortunately, [there is no listener when the plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/master/guice/src/main/java/com/typesafe/plugin/inject/GuicePlugin.java) is shut down, there is an onStart() method, but not any `onStop() method`.

So either you fork the plugin, either you integrate Guice yourself in the onStart/onStop methods of the Global object.

Comment: Thanks Nico, just as I suspected. Thanks for your help.